# osx - Invalid binary when upload mac app on Appstore

Tags: macos, app-store

I have error when uploading mac app on app store. This error in below:

> Invalid Executable or Signature - Your app could not be re-signed by
>   the App Store for distribution, because of an issue with the app's
>   executable (MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/file.o) or its
>   signature. The app may have been built or signed with non-compliant or
>   pre-release tools.
>
> Though you are not required to fix the following issues, we wanted to
>   make you aware of them:
>
> Invalid Signature - the executable at path MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/file.o is not
>   signed. Refer to the Code Signing and Application Sandboxing Guide for
>   more information.

I use xcode tool validate this package and it's successful. But when uploading this package on appstore, it notices "Invalid binary".

Do you know what the error is? I checked the provisioning profile and bundle id are valid.

Answer (score 1):

The file mentioned in the error message (`Contente/Resources/file.o`) probably doesn't belong in your application bundle. Unless it's something important, you should remove it, as it's unlikely to be doing anything useful for you. (It's probably only in your project by mistake.)